# Running management command that take very long in django

Tags: python, django, nginx

I want to call management command from view in Django. The problem is that execution takes very long and nginx gives me 504 or 502 if I increase timeout.

Is there a solution for that?

Comment: Well, then it seems your management command takes very long and breaks somewhere. Can you post the error message from your uwsgi or django log?

Comment: @schwobaseggl I'm absolutely sure that management command works fine, because I can just run it separately

Comment: Increasing the timeout is rarely the proper solution. You should consider executing the command asynchronously, using e.g. a celery task. Can you post the view code, maybe something is off there.

Comment: Management commands are there to be called from the console or a script. So, why are you running them in a web request?

Comment: @schwobaseggl I totally agree. But I am looking for fastest to implement solution. Celery requires additional dependency at least.

Comment: @KlausD. Because I'm too lazy to rewrite the code. It was supposed to be ran from shell, but plans changed. But it's not about management command, it's about code that takes a lot of time to execute.